# Hdmi to dvi oddness

Tags: hdmi, macbook-pro, dvi, external-display

I have a retina macbook pro (with two thunderbolt ports and one hdmi port). I just bought an hdmi to dvi [adaptor](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000FUVNX8) but it doesn't work right when I plug it into my hdmi port:

- The monitor goes to sleep like there is no signal from the laptop
- The laptop adds a new display that I can arrange in system prefs, lose windows in, move my cursor, etc. I just can't see it.
- When I remove the adaptor, the laptop does not seem to notice and the added desktop is never removed.

I've tried with two laptops and three monitors. I've attempted reseting the pram and the smc.

I have found that if I plug this adaptor into my mini-display-to-hdmi adaptor, it works correctly. Straight hdmi to laptop works also. So (dvi->hdmi->mini->laptop) works, (dvi->hdmi->laptop) fails. That's pretty weird, I think.

It seems there is some communication failure between my hdmi port and the adaptor.

I've exhausted most of my regular tools for this sort of problem so I was wondering if it is possible to use some sort of low-level inspection tool (like dtrace) to explore how this adaptor is acting. I would prefer to learn what is going wrong to getting another adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hdmi side of my adapter is a solid 2 millimeters shorter than my regular hdmi cable. I'm going to say that it just can't get a solid connection when I plug it into my laptop, but it can get that connection when plugged into another adapter.